# javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory is a restricted class error with GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-social

I have a **Spring Social** application that I am deploying on **Google App Engine**, but I'm getting the following error during one of my application workflows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:209)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:333)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:165)
    at org.springframework.social.support.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory$HttpComponentsClient_4_1.getInstance(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.social.support.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.<init>(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java:79)
    at org.springframework.social.support.ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector$HttpComponentsClientRequestFactoryCreator$1.<init>(ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector.java:68)
    at org.springframework.social.support.ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector$HttpComponentsClientRequestFactoryCreator.createRequestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector.java:68)
    at org.springframework.social.support.ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector.getRequestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactorySelector.java:44)
    at org.springframework.social.oauth2.ProtectedResourceClientFactory.create(ProtectedResourceClientFactory.java:56)
    at org.springframework.social.oauth2.AbstractOAuth2ApiBinding.<init>(AbstractOAuth2ApiBinding.java:60)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.<init>(FacebookTemplate.java:107)
    at saket.fb.controller.FaceBookController.attack(FaceBookController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
```

How can I overcome this?

I have seen related/similar posts/questions, but those do not seem to answer the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open your own sockets - SSL or otherwise - on App Engine. Instead, you must use the [URLFetch API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) to make external requests.